# Can't compile C library

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to create my first C library, but I just can't compile it.

I'm trying to compile it this way on Fedora: `gcc -o clear.o clear.c`, but I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':

(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

And this is the file I want to use as a library (`"clear.c"`):

```
#ifndef _CLEAR_H_
#define _CLEAR_H_
#ifdef _WIN32
    void clearScreen() {
        system("cls");
    }
    #endif
#elif __APPLE__
    #include "TargetConditionals.h"
    #if TARGET_OS_MAC
        void clearScreen() {
            system("clear");
        }
    #else
    #   error "This Apple platform is not supported"
    #endif
#elif __linux__
    void clearScreen() {
        system("clear");
    }
#elif __unix__
    void clearScreen() {
        system("clear");
    }
#elif defined(__unix__) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
#include <sys/param.h>
#if defined(BSD)
    void clearScreen() {
        system("clear");
    }
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: You can't create an executable from it; you need to create an object file (`gcc -c`) and then build the object file into the static library (`ar rv libyourname.a objectfile.o`) or shared object (probably `gcc -shared -o libyourname.so objectfile.o`).

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite! Will do a better job researching next time

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler!

Comment: @KenWhite: for this problem, most of the 'undefined reference to main' questions (and therefore answers) are from when someone is trying to create a program and is missing the key file, somehow, which is rather different from the problem here.  The advice to search is valid, but it isn't always straight-forward.

Comment: @KenWhite: I understood what you said and I'm really going to do a deeper research next time. I'd like to thank you again

Comment: I've deleted my earlier comments, because I'm afraid they're misleading readers. I've also upvoted your question; it's a well-written question and contains all of the relevant details, just as it should.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, object (`.o`) files as output must be created with the `-c` option to disable the linker. Therefore, to create your object file, run `gcc -c -o clear.o clear.c`.

Next, you probably want to create an actual library, rather than just an object file. To create a shared (dynamically-linked) library (most common), you must specify the `-shared` option. So, once you've made the object file, run `gcc -shared -o libclear.so clear.o` (if you are on Windows, you want a `.dll` instead, so `gcc -shared -o libclear.dll clear.o`).

If you instead would like a statically-linked library, use `ar` on the object files and the `.a` extension instead (`ar rcs libclear.a calc_mean.o`)

Comment: Thank you very much @GoldDragon! I can't upvote your answer... This is what I'm getting: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. You're a newbie to the site, they don't post your votes to avoid abuse. When you ask or answer some questions well, you will gain rep.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I guess I'll improve my reputation here when I start to code better.

Comment: sorry for bothering you, but how do I include my dynamically-linked library in another .c file? Do i need to create something like clear.h ? If so, how do I do that from the libclear.so library?

Comment: So you would need a `clear.h` file with a bunch of `extern` function declarations to `#include` in your application. Move your `libclear.so` to somewhere on your library path. Then use the `-lclear` option on gcc. The `-l???` option searches your library path for a library called `lib???.so` and links it in (??? is any valid string).

Comment: I didn't really understand what you said... Are you telling me to create a new file called  `clear.h` and to copy exactly what I had on `clear.c` but to put `extern` in front of the functions definitions in `clear.h` ? And how do I find my C library path on Linux to `cp libclear.so /library/path/`?

Comment: Each function should be declared in the header, without its body and with `extern` preceding it. In your case, with just one function, all you need is one line (plus the header guards) : `extern void clearScreen()`. Any directory on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will do for holding the `.so` file, or you can add an entry to that environment variable

Comment: Gonna try that now! Thanks!

Comment: So I successfully added libclear.so to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH (it's located on `/usr/local/lib`). And I created the following `clear.h` file: `#ifdef _CLEAR_H_` #new line here#
`extern void clearScreen(); # new line here#
`#endif`

Comment: But now when I try to compile my C file that uses the `clearScreen` function I get `cnh.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to clearScreen'` `cnh.c` is the file that uses the `clearScreen` function

Comment: you need `#ifndef` rather than `#ifdef` in a header guard.